# Graphql saying Validation error of type undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

So I am running a gql query on a React app and passing some default variables. But when the query runs I'm getting this error:

> Error: GraphQL error: Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'firstname' in type 'HealthcareWorkersPage' is undefined @ 'healthcareWorkers/firstname'

This is the query in the .js file :

```
export const GET_PROFILES = gql`query healthcareWorkers($pageNo: Int = 0, $pageSize:Int =  6) {
        healthcareWorkers(pageNo: $pageNo, pageSize: $pageSize) {
            firstname
        }
    }`;
```

Earlier the above query was :

```
export const GET_PROFILES = gql`query {
healthcareWorkers($pageNo: Int = 0, $pageSize:Int =  6) {
        healthcareWorkers(pageNo: $pageNo, pageSize: $pageSize) {
            firstname
        }
    }
    }`;
```

Notice the `{}` after the query keyword. But in this case I got an error saying `Syntax Error: Expected Name, found $`

I use this query on the playground and it works without any issues:

```
    query{
  healthcareWorkers(pageNo: 1, pageSize:6) {
    healthcareWorkers {
      firstname
    }
  }
}
```

The healthcareWorkers Schema:
[image: Schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstname` field lives inside `healthcareWorkers` type. Try this query:

```
export const GET_PROFILES = gql`
  query healthcareWorkers($pageNo: Int = 0, $pageSize: Int = 6) {
    healthcareWorkers(pageNo: $pageNo, pageSize: $pageSize) {
      healthcareWorkers {
        firstname
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked!!! Been scratching my head for an hour over this!